# How can I see which users are taking up space in /dev/sdb1?

Tags: filesystems

I used df -h to check disk space on a GPU that I want to use to train a model. Currently, there are a couple of other users who are also using the same GPU via PuTTY and I want to see which user is using up the most space. How can I check the amount of disk space used by user in /dev/sdb1? Thank you in advance.

[image]

(If I have posted in the wrong Stack, I am sorry. I thought my question was a more general Linux subject.)

Comment: Do you have root on the system?

Comment: As a first approach, check space used in /home: `du -s /home/*`. However, `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` are hot candidates, too. You could look for large files with `find /var/tmp -type f -size LARGENUMBER -exec ls -l {} +`. Which doesn't find space used up by many small files (but you seem to do machine learning, where files tend to be large I would think). Unfortunately, there is no simple answer, but you will find more complete solutions at https://serverfault.com/questions/94663/disk-usage-per-user-in-linux-unix.

Comment: @jsbillings I can access the root account. Is that what you mean? I also gave myself sudo privileges by modifying the /etc/sudoers file by using the root account.

Comment: @berndbausch Thank you for the suggestions! I'll try them out and also take a look at the other comments in the link

Comment: `sudo du -sk /home/* | sort -rn` is my suggestion. `sudo du -sk /home/.* | sort -rn` , too ( counts `.ecryptfs` space, too).

Comment: @waltinator thanks! your suggestion worked.

Comment: Another thing you can do is enable the quota feature on your filesystems.  That will tell you how much each user is using per filesystem.